# Detect touch on UIBezierPath stroke, not fill

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if a user tapped near a CGPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143704/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-tapped-near-a-cgpath)

I'm following Apple's guide from here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html

to try and detect a touch event only on the stroked portion of my UIBezierPath.  If I use the UIBezierPath method, containsPoint, it works fine, but it detects touch events on the stroke and the fill portion of the UIBezierPath, and I want it to only occur on the stroked portion.

Following Apple's guide (at listing 3-6 of the link), I created this function:

```
- (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)point onPath:(UIBezierPath*)path inFillArea:(BOOL)inFill
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
    CGPathRef cgPath = path.CGPath;    
    BOOL    isHit = NO;

    // Determine the drawing mode to use. Default to    
    // detecting hits on the stroked portion of the path.    
    CGPathDrawingMode mode = kCGPathStroke;    
    if (inFill)        
    {   
        // Look for hits in the fill area of the path instead.
        if (path.usesEvenOddFillRule)
            mode = kCGPathEOFill;
        else
            mode = kCGPathFill;
    }

    // Save the graphics state so that the path can be
    // removed later.
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, cgPath);

   // Do the hit detection.
   isHit = CGContextPathContainsPoint(context, point, mode);
   CGContextRestoreGState(context);
   return isHit;
}
```

When I call it, I get:

Error: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Error: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
Error: CGContextPathContainsPoint: invalid context 0x0
Error: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0

Here's my view's drawRect function, and my code to create my path:

```
- (UIBezierPath *) createPath {
    static UIBezierPath *path = nil;
    if(!path) {
        path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(35, 45, 250, 250)] retain];
        path.lineWidth = 50.0;
        [path closePath];
    }    
    return path;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
*/ 
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code

    //draw a circle
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [self createPath];

    //set stroke width
    aPath.lineWidth = 50.0;

    //set stroke color
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];

    //stroke path
    [aPath stroke];

    //close path
    [aPath closePath];

    //add a label at the "top"
    UILabel *topLabel;
    topLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, -5, 80, 25)];
    topLabel.text = @"The Top";
    [self addSubview:topLabel];
}
```

I'm then trying to call the containsPoint function inside of touchesMoved, like this:

```
if (![self containsPoint:c onPath:[self createPath] inFillArea:NO]) return;
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? This post is #1 on the internet for all questions related to this, but there's no answer :)

Comment: I add my voice to shawnall's, have you managed to get this solved?? Hope you can share teh solution if you have any

Answer (score 4):

When you're currently not drawing (as in the `touchesMoved` method), there is no current context, so `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will return NULL.

As all you're doing with the context is to use its current path, you could just as well use [`CGPathContainsPoint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathContainsPoint) instead of `CGContextPathContainsPoint`.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks.  How would I call CGPathContainsPoint?  Calling it like: if (!CGPathContainsPoint([self createPath].CGPath, nil, c, false)) return; Results in the same thing as UIBezierPath.containsPoint, as it seems to pick up both the stroke and fill areas.  Calling it like: if (!CGPathContainsPoint([self createPath], nil, c, false)) return; doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it won't work this way. I didn't notice the fillMode parameter. Apparently you need a CGContext to do hit detection on the stroke part. Perhaps you could create a small bitmap context for this, using CGBitmapContextCreate (you'll find lots of questions about this on SO).

Answer (score 1):

Apple's example assumes you're working inside a graphics context. You're not, so you can just add two lines to the method:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size); // ADD THIS...
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); // ...before this
```

and

```
CGContextRestoreGState(context); // after this...
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); // ADD THIS
```

I just ran into the same problem, and this fixed it for me!

Comment: What does this do exactly? It keeps the context from being nil, but none of my CGPoints are registering within the UIBezierPaths I give it.