# Detecting touch on a thick UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics, uibezierpath

In a drawing section of my application, a user should be able to select a path they created. `UIBezierPath` has a handy method `containsPoint:` which works well in most cases, but it's exceptionally bad when the line drawn is close to straight with no curves. Getting your finger to hit a straight line is very hard.

It seems the method only checks a very narrow line along the path, and even setting `lineWidth` property of the path to a larger value has no effect on the results of the `containsPoint:` test.

I've looked at similar questions, like this one: [Detect touch on UIBezierPath stroke, not fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146677/detect-touch-on-uibezierpath-stroke-not-fill) but was unable to modify the solution to look at "an area around the path", it only seems to look at the thin line at the centre of it.

**Edit**

A working, but intensive solution that I came up with is to convert the path into a `UIImage` and check the colour of that image at the point requested. If the alpha component is greater than zero, the path intersects the touch.

This looks like this:

```
// pv is a view that contains our path as a property
// touchPoint is a CGPoint signifying the location of the touch
PathView *ghostPathView = [[PathView alloc] initWithFrame:pv.bounds];
ghostPathView.path = [pv.path copy]; // make a copy of the path
// 40 px is about thick enough to touch reliably
ghostPathView.path.lineWidth = 40; 
// the two magic methods getImage and getColorAtPoint: 
// have been copied from elsewhere on stackoverflow 
// and do exactly what you would expect from their names
UIColor *color = [[ghostPathView getImage] getColorAtPoint:touchPoint];
CGFloat alpha;
[color getWhite:nil alpha:&alpha];

if (alpha > 0){
// it's a match!
}
```

Here are the helper methods:

```
// in a category on UIImage
- (UIColor *)getColorAtPoint:(CGPoint)p {
    // return the colour of the image at a specific point

    // make sure the point lies within the image
    if (p.x >= self.size.width || p.y >= self.size.height || p.x < 0 || p.y < 0) return nil;

    // First get the image into your data buffer
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    int byteIndex = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] * ((bytesPerRow * p.y) + p.x * bytesPerPixel);
    CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) / 255.0;
    CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) / 255.0;
    CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) / 255.0;
    CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;

    free(rawData);

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
}

// in a category on UIView
- (UIImage *)getImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale]);
    [[self layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

**Edit**

Great answer by Satachito, just want to include it in Obj-C for completeness. I'm using 40 pt stroke as it's closer to Apple recommended minimum touch target size of 44x44 pixels.

```
CGPathRef pathCopy = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(originalPath.CGPath, nil, 40, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineJoinMiter, 1);
UIBezierPath *fatOne = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:pathCopy];
if ([fatOne containsPoint:p]){
    // match found
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 'CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath'

```
    let org = UIBezierPath( rect: CGRectMake( 100, 100, 100, 100 ) )
    let tmp = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(
        org.CGPath
    ,   nil
    ,   10
    ,   CGLineCap( 0 )  //  Butt
    ,   CGLineJoin( 0 ) //  Miter
    ,   1
    )
    let new = UIBezierPath( CGPath: tmp )
```

Makes stroked path of original path. And test hit using both original and stroked path.

Comment: Excellent! This gives me the same results as the convoluted method I came up with, but about 100-200 times faster.

Answer (score 2):

**update swift 3**

```
  let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter,
                                radius: radius,
                                startAngle: startAngle,
                                endAngle: endAngle,
                                clockwise: true)
        path.lineWidth = arcWidth
     let tmp:CGPath =  path.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: arcWidth,
                                  lineCap: CGLineCap(rawValue: 0)!,
                                 lineJoin: CGLineJoin(rawValue: 0)!,
                                 miterLimit: 1)
        let new = UIBezierPath( cgPath: tmp )
```

**update for objective c**

```
 UIBezierPath* path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[path addArcWithCenter:arcCenter
                radius:radii
            startAngle:startAngle
              endAngle:endAngle
             clockwise:YES];
CGPathRef tmp = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath([path CGPath], NULL, self.arcWidth, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineJoinRound, 1.0);
UIBezierPath* newPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[newPath setCGPath:tmp];
```